# Why we see so many downvotes on questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

Every time I see newest questions in any tag there are so many downvotes on questions ...

Absolutely the voting system on questions are to filter questions by their quality not to punish or something like that. What made me think that something is not right is and this system is not really filter questions good is that there are too many downvotes on questions... Is it what really expected to be ?

I uploaded a photo as an example

[Random screenshot from PHP Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfjlO.png)

**We can see only 2 questions with upvotes** , **18 Downvoted questions** and 29 questions unvoted.

Is it really what we expect questions should be on StackOverflow or Is there any problem ? What you suggest to make questions better ?

### My suggestions :

- Improving new users and guide them better at there start point , Something like a *getting started* video or something like that (If really those questions are bad and deserve downvotes)
- Improve voting system and prevent arbitrary voting (If you think users upvote if they like something or they downvote if they dislike a post and not based on SO Rules)
- Change SO rules if users questions are not fit in SO Rules and they want to change them
- Change downvote points (For example Like downvoting answers)
- *Anything else...?*

Comment: I think it's fine. Most new PHP questions aren't very good.

Comment: check how many downvoted question with user that have 1Rep and no badge (didn't take the site tour) ... you will probably find this logical

Comment: @Don'tPanic So maybe we need to make a good guide to make people ask good questions ?

Comment: *Change SO rules if users questions are not fit in SO Rules* --> so we should change countries laws because some user aren't following them? don't you think we should instead *punish* them? by downvoting for example?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why not forcing new users to take the site tour ?!

Comment: @TemaniAfif If Some users aren't following them , Then you are right but if most users don't follow them then there is a problem

Comment: @M4HdYaRb when a website force you to read *terms and condition* before submitting things, do you read them before checking the box? I don't think so. Forcing people to take the tour will not force them to ask better question

Comment: @M4HdYaRb Yeah, how to guide new users to ask good questions is something that's been discussed here quite a bit, and there have been various ideas as to how to accomplish that. Did you know about the Ask Question Wizard that's being tested currently, for example?

Comment: "So maybe we need to make a good guide to make people ask good questions ?" We have a lot of guides for this. The problem is new users often don't care enough to put in the effort, or have never learned/been taught how to ask a good question and think critically.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know what you say TBH I don't read TaC but when I open an app and The app take a quick tour for how to use the app I usually use the tour , Maybe the guide is too long

Comment: @ZeroRequiem I know there are so many guides and there are not only on SO but on so many sites. I mean it can be improved. Maybe there is a reason that some people don't read them

Comment: I think the sympathy upvotes I've been seeing lately are more problematic.

Comment: The guide is too long... But writing a good Q is HARD... So the guide should be long to be helpful. Users don't want to read it... But that one is hardly Stack's fault, no?

Comment: I think that will change when more people do sympathy upvotes to compensate downvotes - I feel that most of my recent downvotes gave +3 to authors... More new folks and less people who try to keep duplicates/low quality posts out will solve that for you soon... (15% non-serious comment). On more serious not none of suggestions look well thought out...

Comment: @temani, I hope that your suggestion, to punish new users with bad questions, was a typographical error. There should never be a goal of punishing anyone for asking a poorly received question. Rather our goal should be to vote on our own perception of the quality of the question, nothing more and nothing less. If the user is punished, it should only be as a result of the site's impersonal algorithm, or in rare cases of egregious behavior, by site moderators.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I used *punish* refering to real people breaking laws and I intended to make a kind of comparaison between the real world and SO to show that downvoting isn't a bad thing. It's a kind a warning that you aren't following rules, it's a *bad* side effect because you made wrong thing. In real world you may simply get *punished* by being obliged to pay an amount of money because you made something wrong. Same here, you will pay from your reputation and you will get a minus. Of course it's not user oriented, but the user shoud understand from this that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the past 30 days, about 14% of questions asked on Stack Overflow have scored < 0.

PHP questions are often more problematic than the norm; over the past 30 days, roughly 23% of them have scored < 0. Still, that leaves a majority that aren't downvoted.

None of this helps you, of course. You're looking for new PHP questions, and... You're seeing a lot of 'em that aren't very good. Consider that you may be a victim of the time of day you've chosen to visit; it's Friday afternoon in the US, and my guess is most folks asking PHP questions right now are feeling a bit desperate and exhausted.

So try this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20score%3a0..%20closed%3a0

Bookmark that search, and make it your default stop when you go to browse questions. Let other folks do the work vetting new questions for a while - save your own downvotes for the problematic questions they've missed.

[Soon, we'll have this functionality built into the system.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320730/custom-question-lists-december-status-update)

Comment: I upvoted your answer and I think you are correct, this time is not really a good time But I don't think simply ignoring bad questions is the best idea

Comment: Can I have Percentage of questions scored > 0 in past 30 days ?

Comment: About 28% across all tags, @M4HdYaR. Folks upvote a LOT more than they downvote.

Comment: And ignoring downvoted questions isn't a terrible idea; [they get deleted eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). Not saying you should *never* look at them, but don't spend too much of your time doing so; it's depressing, and makes it hard to enjoy the work of folks who've done well on the site, of whom there are many. It isn't healthy to focus on the bad things too often.